# How to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my Acer Aspire ZG5?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

I have never used Ubuntu before and I need someone to help me with installation. I have a Acer Aspire one ZG5 and I have no idea about what to do after downloading Ubuntu to my device.
By the way, I want to use an USB Device to install Ubuntu.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

[Install Acer Aspire One ZG5 microphone on Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264505/install-acer-aspire-one-zg5-microphone-on-ubuntu-12-10)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireOne/AOA150

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireOne

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unetbootin. It is a multiplatform software to create bootable USB drives and self explanatory.
There is a screencast @ http://youtu.be/nzpbLssO5AI

The basic steps: (copied from the video description)

- Format USB drive to FAT32 (deletes everything!)
- Choose the already downloaded .iso in Unetbootin
- Click OK and wait
- Restart PC and choose the USB drive in the boot menu

Comment: Ok, I have added those.